# How to find $\int x^2e^{x^2}dx$?

Tags: definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

How to find $\int x^2e^{x^2}dx$? 
I tried integration by parts following ILATE rule but it's not working.Please help!!
What should I take as first function ?
If it's not integrable can you atleast tell how to find the value of definite integration  x=1 to x=2 ?

Comment: This antiderivative can't be expressed in elementary functions.

Comment: what is ILATE rule, just out of interest?

Comment: @Math-fun Order of applying integration of parts: inverse trig, logs, algebraic, trig, exponential. Also sometimes called LIATE, then we have logs before inverse trig. It is just a rule of thumb when you have more than two functions multiplied by each other.

Comment: @wythagoras thanks a lot for the comment.

Comment: I learned LIMPET: Logs, Inverse trig, Monomial/Polynomial, Exponential, then Trig. I live in the US

Answer (score 3):

The gaussian [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) is defined through:
$$\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{t}e^{-x^2}\,dx = \text{Erf}(t).$$
In a similar way, the imaginary error function is defined through:
$$\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{t}e^{x^2}\,dx = \text{Erfi}(t).$$
It follows that:
$$ \int_{0}^{t} x^2\,e^{x^2}\,dx = \int_{0}^{t}\frac{x}{2}\left(2x\, e^{x^2}\right)\,dx = \frac{t}{2}\,e^{t^2}-\sqrt{\pi}\;\text{Erfi}(t). $$
An accurate approximation for the integral over $[1,2]$ can be achieved by integrating termwise the Taylor series of $e^{x^2}$:

$$ \int_{1}^{2}e^{x^2}\,dx = \sum_{n\geq 0}\int_{1}^{2}\frac{x^{2n}}{n!}\,dx = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{2^{2n+1}-1}{(2n+1)\,n!}.$$
A more accurate approximation can be achieved by exploiting the continued fraction representation of the [Dawson's integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DawsonsIntegral.html).

Answer (score 1):

There is no analytical closed form for this integral. It must be evaluated by some numerical procedure, like Gauss-Legendre, for example.

Comment: (He edited the post... it was $\int e^{x^2}$... So, I just edited the integrand, but forgot to do the same to the function name... Sorry...!)

Comment: I wonder why someone gave me a -1, since my answer is *not* wrong...

Comment: I said he edited the post, but despite the name of the function, my answer is not wrong. The integral doesn't have a closed form analytical solution, it must be evaluated numerically.